# Mysql utf8 macedonian text

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, translation, iso

I just tried to insert some macedonian text which i got from my translator via email (gmail in german if that matters) into my utf8_general_ci mysql database but I couldn't figure out how to do it correctly.

Original text: **"Ве молиме внесете"**

1. attempt: just copy and paste the text, result: **"??? ?????? ???????"**
2. attempt: use php's `iconv("ISO-8859-5", "UTF-8", $macedoniantext)` and then copy and paste it, result: **"?ааЕ аМаОаЛаИаМаЕ аВаНаЕбаЕбаЕ"**

Both didn't work at all. Whats the right way to do it?

P.S.: There must be some way to do it because there are already some macedonian texts in the database which are also displayed correctly on the website

Comment: what do you mean by it didn't work at all? what exactly happened

Comment: I added the information to the question.

Comment: [utf-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I got a php function which returns the translation from the database and it works on other places on the website thats why I don't want to change any charset or something.. the question is just how to insert the new translation correctly

Comment: When you say copy and paste, where do you paste? An app of your own or some other client?

Comment: i paste it to the phpmyadmin sql command line

Answer (score 0):

Database should be UTF8 format. when output is using echo utf8_encode($text);